# What is the value of $\lim_{x \to 0} \tan^{-1}(x/m)$ if $m < 0$

Tags: limits

I have a quote from my book that says:

> $\lim_{x \to 0} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac {x}{m}\right)=0$ if $m > 0$ or
>   $\pi$ if $m < 0$

***Added context*** from the book:

The goal is to find the value of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{ \sin(mt)}{t}\mathrm{d}t$

So the above integral is written as the laplace transform:

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{ \sin(mt)}{t}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac {s}{m}\right)$$

And then it states the above (my question) and gets two different results for $\pm m$.

My thoughts:

It's pretty much obvious for the value to become zero for $m > 0$ but I am a bit confused for $m < 0$.

Even if I plot a graph(below) of $\tan^{-1}(-x)$. I can still see that as $x \to 0$ the value of $\tan^{-1}(-x) \to 0$

[image: graph of arctan]

I mean if $x$ was a number or even $\infty$ it's understandable that it can be negative of that number or $-\infty$ but here $x \to 0$ so there nothing negative about $0$.

Can someone please let me know if I am wrong somewhere or my book is wrong?

Comment: Your book might be talking about $\operatorname{atan2}$.

Comment: @Szeto Isn't that used only for programming and softwares what's the point of using it in a book? Moreover, it's not mentioned anywhere if that's $\operatorname{atan2}$.

Comment: $\operatorname{atan2}$ also appears in introductory complex analysis books. You may want to provide the original text, so that people can try to interpret directly what the author really wants to express.

Comment: @Szeto I looked up a bit and I think the above condition is only possible if it's $\operatorname{atan2}$. You may post it as an answer.

Comment: @Szeto Ok, I'll edit and put the original text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your book is wrong. The standard definition of the arc tangent is an odd function and $$\lim_{x\to0}\arctan x=0.$$

By the way,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^\pm}\arctan\frac xm=\lim_{x\to 0^\mp}\arctan\frac x{(- m)}$$ (limits to $\pm$ and $\mp$) and the existence of the limit self-contradicts the claim of the book.

---

If you consider that an implicit reference to the function $\arctan_2$ is made, you have, with the usual convention,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\arctan_2(x,m)=0$$ for positive $m$, and

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\arctan_2(x,m)=\pi,$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\arctan_2(x,m)=-\pi$$ for negative $m$, so that the plain limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you Yves and @Szeto for pointing out $\operatorname{atan2}$.

Answer (score 0):

As you know that $$\arctan (-x)=- \arctan x  $$

Thus if $m<0$ we can write it as

$$\arctan(\tfrac x m)=-\arctan(\tfrac x {-m})=-\arctan(\tfrac x n)\hspace{15pt}n>0
$$

Thus $$\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan(\tfrac x m)=-\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan(\tfrac x {-m})=-\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan(\tfrac x n)=-0=0
$$